# PHP Curl gets 403 error, but browser from same machine can request page?

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-403

I've got this script working with generally no problems. I say generally, because while it retrieves pages from CNN.com, allrecipes.com, reddit.com, etc - when I point it towards at least one URL (foxnews.com), I get a 403 error instead.

As you can see, I've set the user agent to the same as my machine's browser (that was necessitated by sending a request to Facebook's homepage, which returned a message that the browser wasn't supported).

So, basically wondering what step(s) I need to take to have as many sites as possible recognize the CURL request as coming from a real, actual browser, rather than 403'ing it.

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/602.4.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.3 Safari/602.4.8');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fox News appears to be blocking access to their website from any request passing a `USERAGENT`. Simply removing the `USERAGENT` string works fine for me:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks! I had figured setting the USERAGENT to a real browser string wouldn't cause an issue like that, live and learn I guess :)

Comment: Still getting wierd issues... Fox works, but NYTimes needs cookies, so now I'm setting cookies. I figured I would go back to fox with a user agent (like a browser) and accepting cookies, but that doesn't resolve it. I'm really curious about how CURL can be made to look like a real live browser.

Metatags also seem to be less consistent without a user agent, but I can't speak to that factually, just speculating.